# Running rake tasks through capistrano

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I am trying to provision a ruby on rails application using vagrant and chef.  My environment is set up, I have run bundler and my application has been deployed.  However the problem occurs when I try to run rake tasks using capistrano.  I can run rake tasks within the release path through ssh, but running the same command using capistrano does not work.

Below is my deploy.rb file.

```
set :application, 'utrippin.API' 
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:Jaeren/utrippin.git' 
set :repo_tree, 'utrippin.API'

set :deploy_to, "/u/apps/utrippin.API"
set :scm, :git

set :use_sudo, true

namespace :mysql do

task :create do
on roles :all do
within release_path do
  execute "rake db:create"
end
end
end

end
```

When running the mysql:create task I get the following error

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as vagrant@127.0.0.1: rake db:create exit status: 127
rake db:create stdout: Nothing written
rake db:create stderr: bash: rake: command not found
```

Also if I run rake commands using "execute :rake, "db:create"" then it also fails as it fails to connect to the mysql database without a password, even though the correct password is specified in the database.yml file.

I would appreciate any help on how to run rake tasks using capistrano, and an explanation on why I get different results when running in ssh in the same directory with the same user as I do when running using capistrano.

Thanks.

Comment: Do any of these commands work on your server when run locally? You need to do some more diagnostics here.

Comment: Yep, as mentioned in the post these rake tasks work when running using SSH.

Comment: That should be `on roles :db`, as migrations are generally only run on a single designated machine should you have more than one deploy target. Also where is your `rake` located? It seems to be absent from the path used by the Capistrano shell.

Comment: Did you configure capistrano to use rvm? Capistrano will not load up your interactive shell profile.

Comment: Rake is located here:
rake: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake

Comment: I think I have configured capistrano to use rvm....  I added this to my deploy.rb file "require 'capistrano/rvm'" but still get the same error.

Comment: @JaerenCoathup - Does the user which you are using to ssh is vagrant?? It looks more to be environment path issue.